# Asp.net button doesn't submits disabled controls, even with submitdisabledcontrols="true"

Tags: asp.net, disabled-control

I have a page with some disabled controls, it looks like this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" submitdisabledcontrols="true">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upp" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="textchaged_handler" />        
            <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibVerify" runat="server" OnClick="btnVerify_Click" ImageUrl="~/img/imagebutton.png" AlternateText="Verify" />
</form>
```

Programatically, the second textbox is disabled with some server side code, during initialization.

The problem is that, even setting submitdisabledcontrols="true" in the form tag, the disabled textbox value isn't submited  to the server when I click the ImageButton. I checked this with firebug, and also in VS, where the old value is retrieved.

When I press TAB in the first textbox, however, the second textbox value gets posted, no matter submitdisabledcontrols is set or not...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That form attribute states that "Gets or sets a Boolean value indicating whether to force controls disabled on the client to submit their values.", so I think you need to use the client-side disabled property, not the server-side ENabled property, as in:

```
<asp:TextBox .. disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: Both server-side Enabled=false and your code render to disabled="disabled" in HTML... and neither works

Comment: Enabled should be true; it cannot be false.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
control.Enabled = false;
```

Use

```
control.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

Thus from an asp .net perspective the control is still enabled, but it is rendered client-side as a disabled control.

Answer (score 0):

In case any one else comes upon this page like I did, I found that the reason that "submitdisabledcontrols = true" was not working was because of my page doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

when I changed this to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

then it worked.

Hope this helps someone :)